# How to make a digital clock with an 8051 microcontroller

Tags: c

I currently have a project to make a code for the 8051 microcontroller however I am not very sure how to make the timing slower as intended. I have tried many ways to adjust the timer but I am not very sure how to get the exact timing down or how to set a limit for the third digit of the 4 digit seven segment display to be limited to increase until 5 before the second digit increases by 1. Is there anyone that is ablel to help me please?

The code is as shown:

```
#include <c8051f200.h>
#include <setSystem.c>

//display ones/tens/hundreds/thousand at different 7-segment
void starting_display(unsigned int num1, unsigned int num2, unsigned int num3, unsigned int num4)
{
unsigned int x,z;
for(z=0;z<1;z++)
{
    P2 = 0xE0|  num1;
    for (x=0;x<1000;x++);
    P2 = 0xD0 | num2;
    for (x=0;x<1000;x++);
    P2 = 0xB0 | num3;
    for (x=0;x<1000;x++);
    P2 = 0x70 | num4;
    for (x=0;x<1000;x++);
}
}

//Split number to ones/tens/hundreds/thousands
void display(unsigned int x)
{
unsigned int a,b,c,d;
a = x / 1000;
b = (x % 1000) / 100;
c = (x % 100) / 10;
d = (x % 10);
starting_display(a,b,c,d); //Function call to starting_display()
}

void main()
{
unsigned int x = 0, overflow_count;
setSystem();

P1 = 0x00;
TMOD=0x10; //Initialize and configure Timer
TR1=1; //Starts Timer 1
TF1=0; //Clear Timer 1 overflow flag
while(1)
{
    TH1=0x00; //Reload values into TH1
    TL1=0x00; //Reload values into TL1
    while (TF1==0) //Wait for overflow to occur
    {
        display(x); //Function call to split the number
    }

    TF1=0; //Clear overflow flag
    x++;
    if(overflow_count == 100)
    {
        x++;
        overflow_count = 0;
    }
    if (x>2359) //Reset the number
    x=0;
}
}
```

Comment: you should generally avoid divisions when working with microcontrollers because they're very slow (and cost a lot of ROM space on MCUs without a div instruction). Use BCD instead

Comment: @phuclv The 8051 has a DIV instruction, it is no problem. And "slow" depends on the requirements. A digital clock updating its display once a minute does not care about some tens of microseconds for a division.

Answer (score 0):

Split your variable `x` in two variables, and name them `minutes` and `hours`. If it's time to increment `minutes`, do so. If it reaches 60, reset it to 0 and increment `hours`. It that reaches 24, reset it to 0.

To "slow down the time" you can raise the limit for `overflow_count`. It is wide enough to count up to 65535, because you chose `unsigned int` as its type.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand better about the minutes and hours but for the overflow_count. I tried to change to int or increasing the amount **overflow_count == 100** but it doesn't seem to slow down @the busybee

Comment: @Student Would you mind to edit your question and to show us the new code, please? Make sure that you use the increased value for the overflow counter, too. Please keep the old question, just add a header line and the new text and source.

Comment: Hi the busybee, sorry for the long reply but I managed to make the whole thing work already, thanks for all your help

Comment: @Student Alright, great. To help others searching for help with a similar issue, please consider to write an own answer, if mine does not contain all relevant details. See, StackOverflow is not just for people like you getting their specific problem solved. It collects this knowledge for those to come, too. You might consider to take the [tour] to learn more.